# Redirect home page only to another link

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Say I want to redirect only `http://example.com/` to `http://example.com/main/`, how do I do it?

Here's what I am doing right now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^$ main/ [R=301,L]
```

The problem is, it's also redirecting query strings. For example: `http://example.com/?channel=science` is being redirected to `http://example.com/main/?channel=science`.

I don't want only the valid/specified non-empty (i.e. value is specified) query strings to be redirected. For example:

```
http://example.com/?channel
```

**Should** be redirected as well. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use (one or more) RewriteCond between your `RewriteBase` and `RewriteRule` to force rewrites only when querystring matches (or doesn't match with a !) what you want it to.

This will only redirect requests whose querystring matches `cat` or `channel`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)(channel|cat)(.*)$
```

You can also use multple RewriteCond combined with `[OR]` flags if you need one of the conditions, or without the [OR] flag if you need all conditions to be true at the same time. E.g.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)(channel)(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)(cat)(.*)$
```

Also, if you want to remove the querystring from the redirected page, just add a `?` to the end of your redirect url like this:

```
RewriteRule ^$ main/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi, I forgot to include an important detail in my question earlier. I want to specify those query strings that shouldn't be redirected. Please take another look at my question.

Comment: I updated my answer, although it may be not exactly what you asked for. let me know

Comment: That's made it all clear to me. Thank you very much!